# Client puzzle using hash

Tags: hash

When a server is under attack, it send the client the following data:

1. **Nonce** - *a byte array of Y length*
2. **Hash** - *the hash digest of the puzzle solution*

The client has to find X such as Hash(*Nonce*||*Counter*) = *Hash* where Counter is a 32-bit integer value starting from 0.

The client has to return the correct Counter to the server.

1. Is this construction safe?
2. What should be the ideal length of *Nonce*?
3. Does anything change if the length of the *Nonce* is the same length of the hash's block length?
4. What hash function would be ideal in this scenario?